# sed: unterminated `s' command – What does it mean?

Tags: sed

I'm just learning this sed tool. So bear with me and appreciate your help.

This works fine.

```
$ date | sed 's/ /_/g'
Mon_Mar_20_11:02:26_MST_2023
```

But not this one.

```
$ date | sed 's/MST/EDT'
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the last `/`

```
$ date | sed 's/MST/EDT/'
```

or for a visible example:

```
$ date | sed 's/CET/MyMom/'
mån 20 mar 2023 19:46:06 MyMom
```